# playlist is not created on EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI using contentresolver

Tags: android, uri

I am trying to create a playlist using the following code

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();

        cv.put(MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.NAME, "123456");

        //Uri uri = getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.getContentUri("external"), cv);
        Uri uri = getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, cv);
        if (uri != null)
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),uri.toString(), 
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
```

this just would not create any playlist

if i try INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI the playlist is created but even the default app for music in my phone would not show new playlist created

Comment: see http://androidxref.com/5.1.1_r6/xref/cts/tests/tests/provider/src/android/provider/cts/MediaStore_Audio_PlaylistsTest.java and other test classes that use `android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Playlists`

Comment: did it work? you tried that?

Comment: well i am new to learning android and this will take some time if i could get a working example to learn it would be great

Comment: i gave you working example, what else do you need?

Answer (score 0):

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

was the real issue.